# Remove switch from three-way series circuit

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I've got a three-way switch installed in series (I believe that's the correct term - it is not a proper three-way switch, both switches have to be in the on position for the lights to be on.) I had an electrician check, and he said it was wired improperly at the light and I would have to completely rewire it to make it function properly.

So as an alternative, I want to just remove one of the switches, the first on the circuit.

Can I just connect black to black and white to white at that switch, to basically treat that switch as always on?

Comment: Where does the power come into this setup? Is it at the switch or at the light?

Comment: Are the switches three way switches or a switch that has "on" and "off" on the handles?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Without more information we cannot answer. It is possible that you would just make a short circuit which would trip the breaker. If you just want the thing to work, just leave one switch in place but covered so it is not used and just use the other switch to control the light.

Comment: Machavity, its at the light I believe, which I think is the problem. Retired Master Electrician, they're both three way switches (I installed them before I realized the issue). ThreePhaseEel, I will try and get pictures soon.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by both switches must be "on".  A 3-way switch is *always on*. It has two "on" states and it has no "off " state. Do you mean that the light is only on when both switches are up? If you do mean that, is the light on when both switches are down? There are two *correct* ways to wire a pair of 3-way switches. In one way the two switches are opposite (one up and one down) to power the light, and in the other way the switches are the same (both up or both down) to power the light.

Comment: You have a light fixture box and two switch boxes. Is there a single light fixture or more than one? Does the line power enter at the light fixture or does it enter at one of the switch boxes?

Comment: No! Never assume that the black wire is hot or that the white wire is not hot without verifying it.

Answer (score 1):

### How to bypass a plain (1-way) switch

Make sure the switch works *now*, if not you will lose your mind trying to make it work.   Turn the power off first at breaker or fuse.  Unscrew covers and pull switch out of box.  Photograph everything. Then

- Note any ground wires which go to the switch. Grounds are bare, green, or yellow+green stripe.
- Ignoring any ground wires, there are now **exactly two** wires going to the switch.  If there are not, STOP: you will not be bypassing this switch today, and post the photos on SE for advice.
- A wire you can't identify is not a ground wire!
- Remove the switch and splice together those *exactly two* wires.
- Remove any ground wires still on the switch.
- **Do Not Touch** any other wires which may be in the box.

Push it all back into the box and fit a blank cover.